# WHERE Clause for 1 field

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

Im a beginner in sql query and I would like to ask 1 question.

I have 2 table which is dbo.Group_Master and dbo.Group_Assign.

```
     TABLE : GROUP MASTER

| GROUP_ID      |    GROUP_DESC     |
|------------   |:---------------:  |
| PMD           |   POWER MOTOR     |
| ASSY          |     ASSEMBLY      |
| FINANCE       |   FINANCE DEPT    |
| COSTING       | COSTING DEPT      |
| IE            | IMPORT EXPORT     |
| BBC GROUP     | BBC GROUP         |
| PRODUCTION    | PRODUCTION DEPT   |
| PURCHASING    | PURCHASING        |
| SALE          | SALE DEPT         |
| MMASTER       | MATERIAL MASTER   |


          TABLE : GROUP_ASSIGN

| JOB_ID    | STEP_ID   | LOG_NAME  | GROUP_ID  |
|--------   |:-------:  |---------- |---------- |
| J1        |    1      | ACCOUNT   | PMD       |
| J1        |    2      | ACCOUNT   | ASSY      |
| J1        |    3      | ACCOUNT   | SALE      |
| J1        |    1      | FREIGHT   | IE        |
```

When I joined both table and put where clause,  and run query like below

```
SELECT
   a.GROUP_ID,
   a.GROUP_DESC, 
   CASE WHEN b.GROUP_ID IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' end as status 
FROM dbo.GROUP_MASTER A 
LEFT JOIN dbo.GROUP_ASSIGN B ON (B.GROUP_ID = a.GROUP_ID)
WHERE B.LOG_NAME LIKE 'ACCOUNT'
```

[It display result like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsY1W.jpg)

What I want is the result manage to display all the first 2 column and only third column is affected by where clause like below image. Is there any way i can do it ?

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCvr.jpg)

Comment: Can you pls write GROUP_MASTER and GROUP_ASSIGN table? Question is not clear.

Comment: how about right join?

Comment: @KemalGüler updated !

Comment: @GustiArya result same like left join..

Comment: @Safwan check my answer

Comment: @GustiArya yes it displayed all for first 2 column, however for the third column, i want it display based on specific log_name. The way you suggest is include all log_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query ...

```
SELECT
   A.GROUP_ID,
   A.GROUP_DESC, 
   CASE WHEN B.GROUP_ID IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' end as status 
FROM dbo.GROUP_MASTER A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.GROUP_ASSIGN WHERE LOG_NAME LIKE 'ACCOUNT') B ON (A.GROUP_ID = B.GROUP_ID)
```

Comment: yes it displayed all for first 2 column, however for the third column, i want it display based on specific log_name. The way you suggest is include all log_name.

Comment: Yes. It's work. Thank you very much for helping me. May god bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a subquery (to fetch what you want from group_assign first) , like this :

```
SELECT
   a.GROUP_ID,
   a.GROUP_DESC, 
   CASE WHEN b.GROUP_ID IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' end as status 
FROM dbo.GROUP_MASTER A 
LEFT JOIN (select GROUP_ID, LOG_NAME from dbo.GROUP_ASSIGN where LOG_NAME LIKE 'ACCOUNT') B ON (B.GROUP_ID = a.GROUP_ID)
```